# How to switch all 1's and 0's in a string at once

Tags: python, replace

I have a string of numbers made up of 1's and 0's and I'd like to switch all the 1's to 0's and 0's to 1's at the same time.

My main issue is I can only figure out how to do it one at a time so the result is always either 0000 or 1111.

Comment: `inverted = ''.join('0' if ch == '1' else '1' for ch in s)` - there's more clever ways, but this is a trivial and readable way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string contains only 1s or 0s:

```
s = '100110'

out = ''.join('1' if c == '0' else '0' for c in s)
```

Output:

```
'011001'
```

You can also use a translation table ([`str.mktrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) + [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)), which would also work if you have characters other than 0/1 (they would remain unchanged):

```
s = '1002110'

t = str.maketrans('01', '10')

out = s.translate(t)
```

Output:

```
'0112001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this Problem is to chain Pythons String.replace() function. To avoid a String with only 1 or 0 after two replacements, you have to replace one char with an completely diffrent char.

```
test = '10011110101'
test.replace('0', '_').replace('1', '0').replace('_', '1')
```

Output:

```
'01100001010'
```